# Blender Game Engine FPS slows down when encounters a specific object

Tags: game-engine, objects

I am a blender newbie and I am learning how to use BGE.

I've created a landscape with a castle,

put a character in the middle.

Done all the camera settings and started a BGE player.

everything ran completely smooth.

FPS was all ok from the certain distance, facing camera to the character.

but whenever the camera gets close to the character to the close distance

( probably 1,2m away) the FPS drops dramatically and it took me few seconds to

escape from the freeze.

I even lower the polygon count and the texture quality of the character, but

nothing changed.

My computer spec is quite new and it must have no issue running some low

quality background with mid quality single character.

if anyone knows whats wrong with this problem, please enlighten me.

Comment: May you post a screenshot of the physics setting of the player and of the .blend when the situation happens?

Comment: You probably have two rigid body objects colliding, with each other, but one or more has there location's locked so blender constantly tries to calculate the motion- which can't happen, so you get crazy lag.

Answer (score 1):

Switch on `Menu/Game/Show Frame Rate and Profile`.

[image]

It will show you what part of the BGE eats most of the time.

[image]

With that information you can do further investigations and focus on the problematic area.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is the `Physics` I recommend to enable `Menu/Game/Show Physics Visualization`

[image]

After that you will be able to see what the Physics Engine sees:

[image]

Be aware that any intersections of Bounding boxes (red box) increase calculation effort.

Intersections of the physics meshes (green and white meshes) will increase calculation even further.

Therefore they should be with less faces as possible.

- green faces

  - are sleeping physics meshes = no calculation unless a wakeup call
- white face

  - awake physics meshes = calculation until sleep.
- red faces

  - bounding boxes around the physics mesh
  - physics sensor representations such as near and radar.
- cyan

  - i do not know